# Enable/disable Submit and Save button conditionally in InfoPath form

Tags: infopath, infopath2010

I need the InfoPath form to conditionally enable/disable Submit and Save command buttons based on the InfoPath form being created or edited:
 1. **New Form**
    - **Submit** command enabled
    - **Save** command disabled
 2. **Edit Form**
    - **Submit** command disabled
    - **Save** command enabled
The InfoPath form is web browser enabled.

Comment: Use a rule on form load and key off a hidden field. When you first load the form the hidden field will be blank; set your rule condition/actions accordingly (1. New Form). On "Submit" set the value of the hidden field to anything. Now when the form loads the hidden field will no longer be blank, add another rule on form load to handle this scenario (2. Edit Form)

Edit: Sorry, the rules would be on the Submit/Save buttons, not form load. Disable them if the hidden field is blank or not.

Comment: like what user2051770 said, try creatig a field for example. Set that to "0" value as default. Then when user submits, it will set it to 1. 0 = new form and 1 = edit form. Create a rule that will show/hide the buttons based on that value. So when the user opens the form, the buttons will show/hide based on that value.